# Adding a class for null value

Tags: cartography

I'm making a graduated style map and I would like to add a class that would represent null values.  I can add a class for zero (0) value... meaning some of the areas reported zero report, but some areas don't have reports (i.e. null values).

How can I add a class for null values?

Comment: Please use the tags to specify which GIS software you are using. Also, the projection tag doesn't make much sense here.